# Cake PHP: Containable Behavior or Model Unbind - which is good for Optimizing Query in Cake PHP

Tags: cakephp, containable

I'm working on a project based on Cake PHP.On that project recursive = 2 is used and that makes the application slow. Now I need To Optimize Some Query for slow response.
For optimizing Query I can Follow two steps:

#### 1. UnbindModel

#### 2. Containable Behavior

My Question is When I Should use Containable Behavior and when unbinding Models.I Think I need Some Clear Explanation From Cake PHP Expert.

Comment: Always use `Containable` - it's simpler to use, easier to read and does `unbind` under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should always be using either **Containable** or **recursive=>'-1'**
2. **Cache** your queries when it's possible (when you're requesting the same data multiple times)
3. Only ask for what you need using the **fields** parameter
4. Add appropriate **indexes** to your MySQL database tables

Those are just some of the quickest ways to optimizes your queries. There are also ways to optimize queries using **bindModel** for certain requests, or restructuring your tables in certain ways, but those are very situation-specific.